# How do I call a c# class from angular

Tags: c#, angular

Currently learning Angular and so far going very nicely with 1 acception.
I have a angular test site all up and running and doing as expected apart from sending emails.
I have a contact page as below
[image]
Which calls this

```
onSubmit(): void {
this.submitted = true;
if (this.form.invalid) { return; }
else if (this.form.valid) {
  //now to send the email
}
```

So when valid this I want to call the c# code I use in non angular sites to send the email, as below

```
    namespace test.Controllers
{
  public class Email
  {
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
  }

  public class ContactService : Controller
  {
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendMail([FromBody] Email email)
    {
      var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mail.abcabc.com");
      client.Port = 25;
      client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
      client.Timeout = 5000
      client.EnableSsl = true;
      client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("fred@abcabc.com", "~~~~~~~~~~~~");
      var mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
      mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("fred@abcabc.com");
      mailMessage.To.Add(email.To);
      mailMessage.Body = email.Text;
      mailMessage.Subject = email.Subject;
      mailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
      mailMessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
      await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
      return Ok();
    }
  }
}
```

But what I am struggling to figure out is how to link these together, any thoughts please.

Comment: You can't do that directly, JavaScript/TypeScript (Angular) and C# are completely different languages running in different environments. What you can do, with a bit of effort, is author a web service in C# that does anything you want, and then call that from Angular.

Comment: I assume your C# code is in a web API project? That should accept a web request with a json body. I know nothing about angular, but searching "angular call web api" returns many articles that look promising.

Comment: In most cases, you do not want to do it this way. Angular, once compiled, is just HTML and JavaScript that's run on the browser. You do **not** want to have to install dlls on your users machines, and you do not want to have a web API that the browsers access directly without sufficient security because that exposes your mail capabilities a lot more than you should dare. Instead, you'll need yet another piece, a web server specific to your app, that takes the submitted data, writes them to your database, seems emails, etc.

Comment: First: You can not use C# together with your angular project. Second: You may not want to send your mail from client side. --> I would build a server-side service to send the mail that you can trigger via an (encrypted) http-call from your angular application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only use [httpClient](https://angular.io/guide/understanding-communicating-with-http) to call to a web api. but rememeber you need your web API is running.

If your form.value have the properties:`to`,`subject` and `text` you create a service `mailService` -always is good all the calls are called using a service-

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MailService {
   constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){}
   sendMail(data:any){
        return httpClient.post("YOUR URL",data)
   }
}
```

And in your component you use

```
   //don't forget inject in constructor the service
   constructor(private mailService:MailService){}
   
   ...
   if (this.form.valid) 
         this.mailService.sendMail(this.form.value).subscribe((res=>{
            ...in res you get the response..
         })
```

Well you have to fight with CORS, take account if your API return a json or not, ...., but this is the "squeleton"